# Why did Windows Update 'forget' about the updates I did?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates

Until now I've kept my Windows installation offline as I've just used it for gaming offline (I have Ubuntu on a separate disk as my main OS). I recently (last week) decided to download Unreal Engine as I'm beginning to learn C++.

To install Unreal I needed to download SP1, so for the first time, I connected my PC to the internet and began updating; this is where the problem begins.

First, SP1 didn't appear in the list of updates, so I installed all of the other updates hoping it would appear, and after many failures in the optional updates, they eventually finished and SP1 appeared.

Again, many failures in trying to install SP1, approximately 6 days later (around 2-3 hours ago), Windows came out of the blue boot-up screen after finalizing updates. I thought I was finally ready to install Unreal. Open it (Unreal) up and begin installing, it throws out an error that it needs SP1, even though I just finished installing it. I opened Windows Update to make sure I hadn't missed anything, and I hadn't. I figured one more reboot and it should have applied itself.

Following the reboot, I open Unreal to see the same error (No SP1). I open Windows update, and sure enough: all the updates I'd been working at the past 6 days where in a list in front of me, "ready to install".

**TL;DR:** wanted to use Unreal Engine, needed Windows SP1, spent 6 days installing Windows Updates and pulling out my hair at all the errors. Finally "finish" the updates. They've reverted. The past 6 days and dozens of restarts, failures and error codes; wasted.

Why won't Windows take the damn updates? I would have posted this on the Microsoft forums but looking at other people's posts, Microsoft aren't massively helpful.

Comment: I dont you just [download the SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=5842) as a separate file and install that instead?

Comment: Windows update has changed significantly compared to how it worked when SP1 was released.  Have you installed the cumulative patches and the update required to do so?  What happen is not possible based on the information you provide.  Use WSUSOfffline or whatever it's called and install patches in batches

Comment: Install the sp1 from yms link  next the July 2016 rollup and now WU works fine